# jQuery AJAX request TypeError: click is undefinded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI Dialog with buttons. The button "OnTMP" should set the state of the element to "on" as long as the button is pressed. The changing of the state is a database update by an AJAX request. I implemented this functionality with `mousedown` and `mouseup`. However, when I press the button, everything seems to work fine, but once I release it I get the console output

> TypeError: click is undefined jquery-ui.js:10519:5
>
> > dialog<._createButtons/http://iis.local/mysite/js/jquery-ui.js:10519:5
> >
> > jQuery.event.dispatch http://iis.local/mysite/js/jquery-1.11.2.js:4664:15
> >
> > jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle http://iis.local/mysite/js/jquery-1.11.2.js:4333:6

(I included the debugging jQuery script file, not the minified one)

**The widget**

```
$('#pop-up' + id).dialog({
  position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: '#' + id},
  close: function () {
    $('#pop-up' + id).dialog('destroy');
    $('#pop-up' + id).remove();
  },
  height: 50,
  width: 150
  });
  var buttons = [
    {
      text: "On",
      click: function () {
        changeGUIElementState(id, type, "on", false, true);
      }
    },
    {
      text: "Off",
      click: function () {
        changeGUIElementState(bmk, type, "off", false, true);
      }
    },
    {
      text: "OnTMP",
      mousedown: function () {
        changeGUIElementState(bmk, type, "on", true, true);
      },
      mouseup: function () {
        changeGUIElementState(bmk, type, "off", true, true);
      }
    }
  ];
  $("#pop-up" + id).dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
```

**The function changeGUIElementState**

```
function changeGUIElementState(id, type, newState, tmp, saveToDB) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = id;
  obj.type = type;
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log("before ajax");
  // get all the attributes of the elment from the database
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../db/GetElementFromDB.ashx',
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8'
  })
  .done(function (response) {
    console.log("ajax done");
    response.state = newState;
    if (saveToDB) {
      notifyDB(id, type, response);
    }
    // redraw the element
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("request error in changeGUIElementState()");
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });
}
```

So, the console output when I press and release the button is

> before ajax
>
> ajax done
>
> before ajax
>
> TypeError: click is undefined jquery-ui.js:10519:5
>
> ajax done

The element gets redrawn correctly (change of state is change of colour obviously), that's why I didn't look at the console output first.

So any ideas on the issue?

Comment: why are there two "before ajax" and "ajax done" logs? Does `notifyDB(id, type, response);` do a second ajax call? If so it seems like maybe the error is in the `notifyDB` function, since the exception happens after the second "before ajax" log. Also you've left out some code and just commented `//redraw element`. Which element is re-drawn? What does that code do? That could be the source too.

Comment: @ADyson there are two of each because `changeGUIElementState` gets called on mousedown and on mouseup. I left out the code because the error gets displayed before the "ajax done" log. It basically cleans up a canvas element and draws something on it. But that is not the issue.

Comment: Does it work if you put an empty click event into the "onTmp" button? e.g. `click: function () { }`? I think maybe you are expected to supply a click handler for each button, even if it's not used.

Comment: @ADyson seems to work at first glimpse. Will do a few more tests before I can be sure. Be invited to post this as answer and I will accept it once it works in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "click is undefined" message is happening because your "OnTMP" button has no click event handler. jQueryUI requires you to declare a click handler for every button, even if, like in your case, you don't need it. It will assume it is there anyway and try to call it.

To get round it, just add a click handler with an empty function to the definition of the "OnTMP" button:

```
{
  text: "OnTMP",
  mousedown: function () {
    changeGUIElementState(bmk, type, "on", true, true);
  },
  mouseup: function () {
    changeGUIElementState(bmk, type, "off", true, true);
  },
  click: function () { } //empty click handler
}
```